# Broken mysql, cannot fix or remove because of Catch-22 situation with other software

Tags: mysql

I am not a developer, just an everyday user. My technical knowledge is limited. I have been unable to find a solution from other forums or from Mr Google. Consider this a challenge. I shall be concise. My system is Linux Mint 18.3. I use open source medical records software called OpenEMR. This depends on MySQL. Running a package upgrade from the command line, I received errors:

```
Running queries to upgrade MySQL server.
mysql_upgrade: [ERROR] 1010: Error dropping database (can't rmdir './performance_schema/', errno: 17)
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 5
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up adobe-flashplugin (1:20190409.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so is already managed by mozilla-flashplugin.backup.20190407
dpkg: error processing package adobe-flashplugin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                            Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 adobe-flashplugin
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

After this I have made multiple attempts at configuring mysql and purging mysql (in order to reinstall), all failed. When I attempt to remove mysql, the process first wants to remove openemr, for which I am asked to supply my mysql root password. I am 100% certain of my mysql password, but it is not accepted, so the process aborts.

In summary, I cannot fix mysql, neither can I remove it, in the latter case because openemr has to be removed, which cannot be done because mysql packages are corrupted.

As an added bonus, flash-plugin is also affected by this.

People here are my last attempt at recovering from this situation before going for a complete system re-install, which is always a massive pain. The one saving grace is that I do have a backup of my openemr data.

Many thanks.

Comment: "can't rmdir './performance_schema/', errno: 17" you need to address this error. Have you tried removing this directory manually? As an admin? Have you checked the permissions?

Comment: The directory performance_schema does not exist.

Comment: [mysql - Error Dropping Database (Can't rmdir '.test\', errno: 17) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584458/error-dropping-database-cant-rmdir-test-errno-17)

Comment: It clearly exists somewhere. Are you looking in the right location?

Comment: I am unable to access phpmyadmin.

Comment: "performance_schema" should be in /var/lib/mysql but that directory is empty.